# how to set automatic delay after sent 1 mail with social engineer toolkit (Mass Mailer)

Tags: python, email

I try to send messages to all my subscribers with a social engineer toolkit but I don't know how to set an automatic delay.

Firstly, I made list of `5` email addresses and send them with default setting, and then I setting delay in `src/core/config` and change delay time to `15` second, but it does not work. What should I do?

Comment: You need to enhance your question...  How are you using the configuration file? How are you using the mail tool? If you post your code snippet here, some of us can detect the culprit and solve it for you.

Answer (score 0):

In Python, you can use **time.sleep(seconds)** to make the current executing Python program to sleep or delay a few seconds.

```
import time

time.sleep(1) # delays for 1 seconds
time.sleep(15) # delays for 15 seconds
```

Comment: I found this code http://prnt.sc/ek4fo4. i think this is menu for setting delay http://prnt.sc/ek4fp5. i change the default delay from 1 to 60 second. and nothing happens. what wrong ? sorry for my bad english

Comment: I using script for here https://github.com/trustedsec/social-engineer-toolkit. maybe this is directory setting > https://github.com/trustedsec/social-engineer-toolkit/tree/master/src/core/config.baseline. help me please

Comment: just put `time.sleep(60)` , first try to put the sleep value directly and check if it works

Comment: thanks for your answer. i already put this code is not work, because i did not understand about that. can you help me ? where i can put right location.
you can visit https://github.com/trustedsec/social-engineer-toolkit/tree/master/src/phishing/smtp/client/ smtp_web.py and see for full code.